# Possible to change meta data single quotes to dobule quotes in yoast wordpress seo?

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

The yoast wordpress seo plugin puts meta description and meta keywords in single quotes.
The issue here is that many old spiders and directory submission sites do not read meta data in single quotes. 
Also i dont really know if there is any benefit in using single quotes over dobule quotes for meta data.
So i am wondering if it is possible to change those single quotes to dobule quotes?
Thanks

Comment: DEFINITIVE duplicate of [(Plugin) "Yoast meta descriptions" showing in ' ' instead of " "](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28774/plugin-yoast-meta-descriptions-showing-in-instead-of)

Comment: Kaiser - How is that duplication? I am asking HOW to change single quotes to double. Last question was asking to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You can't without directly editing the source of the plugin, which of course is not recommended. I'm curious what spiders this does not work with? They don't follow HTML spec if that's the case.

Comment: You are asking more than one Q aside from the Q in the title. And inside your Q you're asking what makes it a dublicate. Second I double @Milo answer. Third: Because of the details provided in your Q it's in large parts not a wp Q.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, I don't know why this thing keeps popping up but: it just works with single quotes, no need to change anything. Need proof? Ok, here we go:

Search for "WordPress SEO plugin". Find my site, yoast.com, it'll be #1 in most cases. See the meta description showing? Click on the "Cached" link, then open the source for the cache. There it is, in full glory, my meta description, as you've just seen in your search results, encapsulated by: single quotes.

This is of course 100% according to standards, see:

- HTML4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2
- HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attribute-value-double-quoted-state

Thank you for your time.